# Don't create print.scss and screen.scss sass files when installing compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm installing compass via a provisioning tool on my vagrant box and by doing so I create the following files

- print.scss
- screen.scss

Though, I have no use for these files and they remain empty it's becoming annoying having to remove them everytime we provision our vagrant machine.

Is there any way to install compass without creating the default scss files?

```
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Start up Compass Compiling"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
sudo compass init
sudo compass compile
```

My provisioner script

Comment: Why are you having to create a new Compass project so frequently that removing these files is an annoyance?

Comment: Good question. I've added the relevant commands in the provisioner into my question @cimmanon. Can you suggest a better alternative? Shell provisioning is fairly new to me. Although, I'd still prefer it if these un-used files weren't output by the installation; for version-control reasons. I _could_ add them to my gitignore file, however I'd rather they weren't created in the first place.

Comment: Are you telling me that your config.rb is not in your repo?  Because the only thing that characterizes a Compass project is config.rb.

Comment: My config.rb is in my repo, yes. However I can't see anything in the compass.rb file that would cause it to create these unrequired files. @cimmanon

Comment: If you already have a config.rb, you don't need to run `compass init`, you just run `compass compile`.

Comment: So in my provisioner I should check to see if the config.rb file exists, and if so only compass compile? Otherwise compass init, by doing so creating these files, however if I'm in a shell if condition I can manually remove these there and then, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line option you're looking for is `--bare`, though it only works with the `create` option:

```
compass create [optional directory name] --bare
```

Comment: Hi, sorry - what is the [optional directory name] indicating?

Comment: That the command takes an optional directory name?  `compass create --bare` or `compass create foo --bare`

Comment: Right, figured that out - thank you anyway, exactly what I was looking for!